# Color Opacity with Gadfly

Tags: plot, opacity, julia, gadfly

Is it possible to control the alpha property (opacity, or transparency) when plotting with Gadfly?  I am attempting to plot a comparison of distributions.  Any info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, but it is a [planned feature that seems close to being added](https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl/pull/224).

Comment: I saw that guy.  I guess I was hoping that I had missed further development.  Thanks for following up.

Comment: As of now, it still does not work. Interesting to read for this topic: https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl/issues/844

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with `Geom.ribbon`. The following code copy-pastes the plot from [nabble.com](http://julia-programming-language.2336112.n4.nabble.com/Opacity-in-Gadfly-plots-td14894.html) and uses the `Geom.ribbon opacity` issue [on Github](https://github.com/GiovineItalia/Gadfly.jl/issues/611):

```
using Gadfly, DataFrames, Distributions
d1 = Normal(-1);
d2 = Normal(1);
x = -4:0.01:4
y1 = pdf(d1, x);
y2 = pdf(d2, x);
df1 = DataFrame(x = x, y = y1, ymin = 0.0, ymax = y1, d = "d1");
df2 = DataFrame(x = x, y = y2, ymin = 0.0, ymax = y2, d = "d2");
df = vcat(df1, df2)

# No transparency
p1 = plot(df, x = :x, y = :y, ymin = :ymin, ymax = :ymax, color = :d, Geom.line, Geom.ribbon)

# With transparency
p2 = plot(df, x = :x, y = :y, ymin = :ymin, ymax = :ymax, color = :d, Geom.line, Geom.ribbon),
          Theme(lowlight_color=c->RGBA{Float32}(c.r, c.g, c.b, 0.2)))

draw(PNG("test1.png", 12cm, 6cm), p1)
draw(PNG("test2.png", 12cm, 6cm), p2)
```

Plot without transparency:

[image: Plot without transparency]

Plot with transparency:

[image: Plot with transparency]